# l format my Huawei G700-T00 and now l cannot install it again

Tags: google-play-store

Please how can l reinstall google playstore on my Huawei G700-T00. i have tried to install it three time

Answer (score 0):

You can get the .apk of [Google PlayStore over here](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/) get it downloaded over the device memory and try installing it ! I should work for you !

PS: Don't worry about the source it's coming from a trusted source i.e. [AndroidPolice](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/10/31/breaking-google-play-store-update-5-0-31-adds-even-more-material-design-highlights-and-moves-whats-new-to-the-top-apk-download/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Huawei App Store installed then the whole process is a piece of cake. Based on the model you are reffering to, T-00, I guess you have the chinese version so the Huawei App Store should be available in you device.

1. Open Huawei App Store
2. Search for "Google Play Services" and Install it
3. Install "Google Play Store" as well
4. Then in the search bar search for "google"
5. Press the image that shows many products of google, like chrome, gmail, hangouts, google     plus
6. From there download the Calendar Sync that has an icon of a calendar and the Contact Sync that has an icon of person.

Now you can download apps from Play Store, Sync Contacts and Calendar.

For you help I have attached some screenshots.

[image: Huawei App Store 1]
[image: Huawei App Store 2]
[image: Huawei App Store 3]